# Finding roots of equation in $\Bbb{Z}_{14}$, $\Bbb{Z}_{17}$

Tags: number-theory

Find all the roots of the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 - 9x + 6 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$. Use this to factor $f(x)$ in as many ways as possible.

Repeat this process for $x^2 - 9x + 3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell where you're stuck at?

Comment: What have you tried?  If nothing else, there aren't that many numbers in these rings-you can just try them all.

Comment: Hint: For $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, plug in values from 0 to 13 and find the value of the polynomial modulo 14. If plugging 'a' gave you a zero (in $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$), then $(x-a)$ is a factor.

Comment: I really don't know where to begin. Any ideas as in where to start?

Comment: Use the standard quadratic formula.  But be careful in two places - what are the square-roots of 1? and how to halve a number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what **Michael** is describing in his comment (and I'll work out the first equation, since **SwapnilTri** has already discussed it):

It isn't terribly obvious how to factorize the equation in mod 14, so we can set up the quadratic formula to obtain

$$ x \ = \ \frac{9 \ \pm \ \sqrt{9^2 \ - \ 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 6}}{2} \ = \ \frac{9 \ \pm \ \sqrt{57}}{2} \ \equiv \ \frac{9 \ \pm \ \sqrt{1}}{2} \ [\bmod 14 \ ] \ \ , $$

since $ \ 57 \ = \ 4 \cdot 14 \ + \ 1 \ $ .

Now comes the "fun" part.  Using the positive square root, we have the two quotients

$$ \frac{9 \ + \ 1}{2}  =  \frac{10}{2} \ = \ 4 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{9 \ - \ 1}{2}  =  \frac{8}{2} \ = \ 5 \ \  . $$

Since 1 has two square roots, we also want  "-1" in $ \mathbb{Z}_{14} \ $ , so we need to use  13 .  (This checks, as $ \ 13^2 \ = \ 169 \ = \ 14 \cdot 12 \ + \ 1 \ $ . ) This gives us two other quotients,

$$ \frac{9 \ + \ 13}{2}  =  \frac{22}{2} \ = \ 11 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{9 \ - \ 13}{2}  = \ \frac{-4}{2} \ = \ -2 \ \equiv \ 12 \ [ \bmod 14 \ ] \ \   . $$

It is only a little effort to verify that there are *no other* square-roots of 1 .  We now also know which pairs of linear factors go together to produce our quadratic equation.  [As a check, for example, we have

$$ \ (x \ - \ 4) \ (x \ - \ 5) \ = \ x^2 \ - \ 9x \ + \ 20 \ \equiv \ x^2 \ - \ 9x \ + \ 6 \ [ \bmod 14 \ ] \ \ . \ ] $$

$$ \ \ $$

We have something similar for the second equation,

$$ x \ = \ \frac{9 \ \pm \ \sqrt{9^2 \ - \ 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 3}}{2} \ = \ \frac{9 \ \pm \ \sqrt{69}}{2} \ \equiv \ \frac{9 \ \pm \ \sqrt{1}}{2} \ [\bmod 17 \ ] \ \ , $$

so the method will be similar (though  17 being prime now removes the ambiguity discussed below, and it being odd eliminates the solutions with the "negative square-root of 1" ).

[**EDIT -- egreg** makes an important point that modular division can be ambiguous. (This was a matter I was concerned about, which I hope I've now sorted out.)  More properly, for the first pair of quotients above, I should write

$$ \frac{10 \ + \ 14k}{2} \ = \ 5 \ + \ 7k \ \ \text{and} \ \  \frac{8 \ + \ 14k}{2} \ = \ 4 \ + \ 7k \ \ , $$

with $ \ k \ $ being an integer.  But we then obtain our other set of solutions, $ \ 11 \ $ and $ \ 12 \ $ .  Doing this for the second pair of quotients will get us $ \ 4 \ $ and $ \ 5 \ $ .  So in this problem, we have covered all of the "zeroes" of the quadratic equation. ]

Comment: Dividing by $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$ is not really well defined.

Comment: I was away for a while and am just getting back.  I will make an amendment...

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a root of $x^2-9x+6$ in $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
4x^2-36x+24=0
$$
and we can complete the square, as usual:
$$
4x^2-36x+81-81+24=0
$$
that is
$$
(2x-9)^2=57
$$
Since $57=1$, we get
$$
2x-9=1\qquad\text{or}\qquad 2x-9=-1
$$
that is
$$
2x=10
$$
or
$$
2x=8.
$$
We cannot conclude straight away that $x=5$ or $x=4$, because there are other solutions: indeed $10=24$, so we can also have $x=12$; also $8=22$, so we can have also $x=11$.

It's easy to see that $2x=10$ has only the solutions $x=4$ and $x=12$, while $2x=8$ has only the solutions $x=4$ and $x=11$.

However, multiplying by the non invertible element $4$ might have introduced spurious solutions, so we check by division: since $x=5$ is a root, we can divide $x^2-9x+6$ by $x-5$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rr|r}
  & 1 & -9 & 6 \\
5 &   &  5 & -20  \\
\hline
  & 1 & -4 & 0
\end{array}
$$
which gives the decomposition $x^2-9x+6=(x-5)(x-4)$. Now we do the division by
$x-12$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rr|r}
   & 1 & -9 & 6 \\
12 &   & 12 & 36  \\
\hline
   & 1 & 3 & 0
\end{array}
$$
which gives the decomposition $x^2-9x+6=(x-12)(x+3)=(x-12)(x-11)$.

This shows that the multiplication by $4$ has not introduced spurious solutions and that these are the only possible decompositions with monic factors.

Since $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, the usual quadratic formula applies, with the discriminant of $x^2-9x+3$ being
$$
9^2-4\cdot3=81-12=69=1,
$$
so the roots are
$$
\frac{9+1}{2}=5\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{9-1}{2}=4.
$$
Indeed $5+4=9$ and $5\cdot4=20=3$.

Note: equalities are congruences modulo $14$ in the first part and modulo $17$ in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how to proceed here.

**IN $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$**

$x^2-9x+6=x^2+5x+6=f(x)$ *(say)*

$f(4)=16+20+6=42=0 (\mod 14)$

So $(x-4)$ is a factor.

Similarly $(x-11)$, $(x-12)$ and $(x-5)$ are factors.

Now try finding the pair of $(x-4)$ among the three.

The two leftovers are the second set of factor pairs!